# Cartesian product of multiple lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, python-itertools

I have two or more dictionaries and each of them is a list of dictionaries (something like json format), for example:

```
list_1 = [{'Name': 'John' , 'Age': 25} , {'Name': 'Mary' , 'Age': 15}]
list_2 = [{'Product': 'Car', 'Id': 1} , {'Product': 'TV' , 'Id': 2}]
cartesian_product(list_1 * list_2) = [{'Name': 'John', 'Age':25, 'Product': 'Car', 'Id': 1}, {'Name': 'John', 'Age':25, 'Product': 'TV', 'Id': 2}, {'Name': 'Mary' , 'Age': 15, 'Product': 'Car', 'Id': 1}, {'Name': 'Mary' , 'Age': 15, 'Product': 'TV', 'Id': 2}]
```

How can I do this and be efficient with memory use? The way i'm doing it right now runs out of RAM with big lists. I know it's probably something with itertools.product , but i couldn't figure out how to do this with a list of dicts. Thank you.

PD: I'm doing it this way for the moment:

```
gen1 = (row for row in self.tables[0])
table = []
for row in gen1:
    gen2 = (dictionary for table in self.tables[1:] for dictionary in table)
    for element in gen2:
         new_row = {}
         new_row.update(row)
         new_row.update(element)
         table.append(new_row)
```

Thank you!

Comment: [XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: If you need everything in `table` at once that's unavoidable, so... do you?

Comment: The memory-efficient way would be to not do this. Taking a cartesian product is usually avoidable and usually a bad idea. Also, iterating over genexps like that is silly. For example, the outer loop could just be `for row in self.tables[0]:`.

Comment: pandas.DataFrame might be a good fit for this.

Comment: @user2357112 I know cartesian product is not the most memory-efficient way, but I need to use it for what i'm doing, and about generators, as far as I know, it's more efficient to iterate over gens than regular loops, so i'm trying to reduce every memory usage. Thank you!

Comment: @RaimundoManterola: "as far as I know, it's more efficient to iterate over gens than regular loops" - iterating over a generator isn't any more efficient than iterating over any other object. It's usually a bit slower, actually. The difference is that creating a generator is much less memory-intensive than creating a list or other materialized data structure, but here, you already *have* your `tables` data structure eating memory. Making a generator isn't going to make the memory requirements of `self.tables` go away.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to the problem posted:

```
list_1 = [{'Name': 'John' , 'Age': 25} , {'Name': 'Mary' , 'Age': 15}]
list_2 = [{'Product': 'Car', 'Id': 1} , {'Product': 'TV' , 'Id': 2}]


from itertools import product
ret_list = []
for i1, i2 in product(list_1, list_2):
    merged = {}
    merged.update(i1)
    merged.update(i2)
    ret_list.append(merged)
```

The key here is to make use of the `update` functionality of `dicts` to add members. This version will leave the parent dicts unmodified.  and will silently drop duplicate keys in favor of whatever is seen last.

However, this will not help with memory usage. The simple fact is that if you want to do this operation in memory you will need to be able to store the starting lists and the resulting product. Alternatives include periodically writing to disk or breaking the starting data into chunks and deleting chunks as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the dictionaries to lists, take the product, and back to dictionaries again:

```
import itertools

list_1 = [{'Name': 'John' , 'Age': 25} , {'Name': 'Mary' , 'Age': 15}]
list_2 = [{'Product': 'Car', 'Id': 1} , {'Product': 'TV' , 'Id': 2}]
l1 = [l.items() for l in list_1]
l2 = [l.items() for l in list_2]
print [dict(l[0] + l[1]) for l in itertools.product(l1, l2)]
```

The output is:

> [{'Age': 25, 'Id': 1, 'Name': 'John', 'Product': 'Car'}, {'Age': 25,
>   'Id': 2, 'Name': 'John', 'Product': 'TV'}, {'Age': 15, 'Id': 1,
>   'Name': 'Mary', 'Product': 'Car'}, {'Age': 15, 'Id': 2, 'Name':
>   'Mary', 'Product': 'TV'}]

If this isn't memory-efficient enough for you, then try:

```
for l in itertools.product(l1.iteritems() for l1 in list_1,
                           l2.iteritems() for l2 in list_2):
    # work with one product at a time
```

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items'

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3:

```
import itertools

list_1 = [{'Name': 'John' , 'Age': 25} , {'Name': 'Mary' , 'Age': 15}]
list_2 = [{'Product': 'Car', 'Id': 1} , {'Product': 'TV' , 'Id': 2}]
print ([{**l[0], **l[1]} for l in itertools.product(list_1, list_2)])
```